# How to position searchbox to the top of the page in Shiny?

Tags: html, r, shiny

How can I position the search bar to the top of the page here in Rshiny. I would prefer to do a solution using HTML within shiny.

Here is what it currently looks like. I also tried to position it left and that wasn't quite what I was looking for. I was looking to have the table take up the entire main page and have the filter up at the top.

[image]

Below is a reproducible example using R:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Tabsets"),
  sidebarLayout(position = "right",
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput('search', "Search"),
      tags$div(class="header", checked=NA,
               tags$p("Ready to take the Shiny tutorial? If so"),
               tags$a(href="shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial", "Click Here!")
               
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(id = "tabsetPanelID",
                  type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Tab1", DTOutput('DT1')),
                  tabPanel("Tab2", DTOutput('DT2')),
                  tabPanel("Tab3", DTOutput('DT3'))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$DT1 = renderDT(iris)
  DTProxy1 <- dataTableProxy("DT1")
  
  output$DT2 = renderDT(iris)
  DTProxy2 <- dataTableProxy("DT2")
  
  output$DT3 = renderDT(iris)
  DTProxy3 <- dataTableProxy("DT3")
  
  observeEvent(c(input$search, input$tabsetPanelID), {
    updateSearch(DTProxy1, keywords = list(global = input$search, columns = NULL))
    updateSearch(DTProxy2, keywords = list(global = input$search, columns = NULL))
    updateSearch(DTProxy3, keywords = list(global = input$search, columns = NULL))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```